# SQLcipher : Release a 64-bits version App Bundle for Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, 64-bit, release, sqlcipher

I want to publish my Android mobile application which uses an **encrypted SQLCipher database**.

During deployment my release does not meet the obligation to provide a **64-bit version on Google Play**.

I followed the prescriptions for [Support 64-bit architectures](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) but no results.

I need help please!

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mdc.droit"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'

}


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'nl.littlerobots.cupboard-tools:sqlcipher:0.3.1' //SQlCipher implementation HERE
}
```

[Android Studio Analyze APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETtfj.png)

[Google Play Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUdGM.png)

Answer (score 0):

We added 64-bit support to SQLCipher for Android in [February of 2017](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-3-4-1-release/1962). You may need to update your dependencies, the latest version of SQLCipher for Android is 4.4.0.

Comment: I tried it using the directions [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/) and update my dependencies with : implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.4.0@aar'
implementation "androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1" But in the code the imortation is not resolve  ERROR: "Unresolved reference: net"